# Oracle how to cast result of a select into a number as data for the next query?

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose:

```
select * from a where id = (select id from b);
```

Where `id` is a number column in table `a`, and `id` is a varchar column in table `b`.

How can i transform the result of `select id from b` into a number?

Seems like this doesn't work:

```
select * from a where id = to_number((select id from b));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from a where id = (select to_number(id) from b);
```

Btw, if you have more than 1 or 0 rows in `b` - you need to replace `=` operator with `IN`